# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 while fetching data from rest api

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

Whenever I try to run Flutter my app, the first time it will show an error like this: [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkgLd.png)

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

If I run its again by using ctrl+s, it works fine and all the errors are gone: [success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvV54.png)

This error is only appearing a few seconds, after it displays the wrong data until I refresh the application.

https://pastebin.com/LYe88Bys

**Error-Causing Code:**

```dart
CarouselSlider.builder(
  options: CarouselOptions(viewportFraction: .99, autoPlay: true),
  // itemCount: showp.shows.length.compareTo(0),
  itemCount: showp.shows.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int realIndex) {
    return BannerWidget(
      image: showp.shows[index].bannerImage,
      title: showp.shows[index].showTitle,
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: you should probably be using a FutureBuilder since you are making an async fetch.... Probably the reason it works after you ctrl+s is because the result first wasnt available but after you hot reload it has already been fetched

Comment: @pedropimont so is its possible to use provider with future builder because i doesn't find any example where we use both provider or future builder